# Sandbox for Windows applications

Tags: windows-10

**Problem:**

1. Many programs install files onto the `C:\` drive even if the installation directory is specified as a folder on a different drive.  This takes up too much space on the `C:\` drive.
2. Some programs create services that are always running even if there is no need for them run. This slows the computer down.

**Requirement:**

I am looking for a software that is sort of a sandbox. It

1. Should run on Windows 10.
2. Need not be free.
3. Should create a Sandboxed environment.It should not allow the software that is being installed to install to the `C:\` Drive.

   One way of doing this is to capture the system calls of the installed     program, monitor the file access calls and then rewrite all calls that result in file operations in `C:\` Drive so that the file creation happens in a user specified directory.
4. It should stop all the services when I close the sandbox. And restart them when I start the sandbox again.

**Optional Requirements:**

1. Ability to block and allow internet access to the application.
2. Specify the amount of RAM that the program can use.

I could use a Virtual machine. But they take too much space and RAM. Also I will have to create separate virtual machines for each application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe sandboxie?

Comment: @Vinz243 I have heard of it, but haven't really tried it. Does it solve the process issue?

Comment: Sorry, but which issue are you talking about? The the 4th one?

Comment: @Vinz243 Yes. Does it start the services when I open the software and stop them when I close it ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know

Comment: Do you want something like a VM or is that too heavy for you?

Comment: @AidenGrossman This should work for each individual program. I could try it in a VM but it is too heavy and also I would have to install each program on a different machine. Plus it affects the usability

Comment: @AswinPJ okay that makes sense.

Comment: The best solution I could think of is to stick to "portable" version of software and run it under a different user account, so it doesn't gets access to any of your file or system-wide things (this is what Android actually does to prevent programs from tampering with each other and the SD card).

Answer (score 5):

Try Sandboxie. http://www.sandboxie.com/
They've recently launched a version for Windows 10. Altough, I am not sure it can restart the programs as stated at the requirement 4.

Comment: I've been using this for 6 years, works great for malware analysis / other potentially dangerous stuff.